# Add to arraylist in a firebaselistAdapter class in android

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My issue is that am trying to fill my arraylist by adding an object retrieved by firebaselistAdapter method , but it couldn't ,it's not adding objects to the list.
here is the code :

```
comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
refJ = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("comments");
commentsAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Comment>(this, Comment.class, R.layout.item_comment, refJ) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, Comment j, int position) {
        comments.add(j);      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewComment)).setText(j.getJ_nom());
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                  .load(j.getJ_image())
                  .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_outline_black_24dp)  
                  .error(R.drawable.ic_profile)    
                  .resize(300, 250)                        
                  .transform(new CircleTransform())                            
                  .into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewComment));
    }
};
```

all works fine with the firebaselisAdapter and it's perfectly displayed ,; my problem is that I want to add comments to the arraylist of the comments.
I used this code to make sure of thecomments list :

```
    Iterator<Comment> it = comments.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Comment : "+ it.next()+"\n");
    }
```

Here is my json structure: 
 [image: json structure]
and here is the Comment class:

```
public class Comment{
private String j_emplacement;
private String j_equipe;
private String j_image;
private String j_nom;
private Long j_numero;
private String j_prenom;

public Comment() {
}

public Comment(String j_emplacement, String j_equipe, String j_image, String j_nom, Long j_numero, String j_prenom) {
    this.j_emplacement = j_emplacement;
    this.j_equipe = j_equipe;
    this.j_image = j_image;
    this.j_nom = j_nom;
    this.j_numero = j_numero;
    this.j_prenom = j_prenom;
}
```

//getters and setters}

I, found that the list of comments is empty.
Any help would be appreciated ,; THANKS

Comment: Post your json structure

Comment: the problem is statically in android, I want to add comments to the arraylist of the comments

Comment: Just add them with firebase, why do you want to use FirebaseListAdapter?

Comment: Well I can't add it now, am using it cuz I found it easy if there is another solution I'd use it :) ,

Comment: Again, provide me your json structure and i can help you

Comment: here I edited it and added comment class and json structure

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    List<String> commentKeys=new ArrayList<String>();

    DatabaseReference mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("comments").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                commentKeys.add(snap.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```